# Missing charset in phpmyadmin. What to do?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

A friend asked me to add a php dynamic panel in his site whitch is generated by sum web based site generator. I am bulgarian and we use cp1251 edncoding whitch is Cyrillic Windows. But the site is generated with iso-8859-5 charset and is inpossible to convert it. If I use different cyr charset there are only question marks displayed in the page. And this encoding iso-8859-5 does not exsits in phpmyadmin. Give me please some advise what to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've tried to use utf8 in the mysql but the result is the same.

Comment: Where are you outputting what coming from where? Can you show some code?

Comment: I would look for a way to convert project to... unicode/UTF-8. And a database to unicode/UTF-8. It's not impossible, but will save you a lot of pain in the future. The problem you have is just a beginning, those who are not using unicode are burning in eternal fire >:-E~

Comment: The page encoding is iso-8859-5 and there is no such charset in phpmyadmin changing the page encoding whatever utf8 or else make the page go to hell.

Answer (score 1):

I've manage somhow to change it to utf-8 and it's fine now